# Re-arranging powers for root test

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\frac{(n+1)^{2n}}{(4n-6)^n}$

I'm confused as to how to change the 2n to an n in the numerator. I tried $(n^2+2n+1)^n$ as it made sense since that is $(n+1)^2$ but it is not correct

Comment: $$(n+1)^{2n} = ((n+1)^2)^n $$

Comment: Your procedure is correct for that part.

Comment: If the series  is $\sum \frac{(n+1)^{2n}}{(4n-6)^n}x^n$, it will converge only at $x=0$.